# Scroll position in template React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with scroll in React. How can I use scrolling to element in Template? I'd like to scroll to one of the elements in this.props.children by using navigation of Header.

```
class Template extends React.Component {
handleClick = () => {
    const tesNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
    window.scrollTo(0, tesNode.offsetTop);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header click={this.handleClick} ></Header>
                {this.props.children}
            <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've made some example here https://codesandbox.io/s/48k35w1107, check this out.